# How to add a "helper column" in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created the following pivot table showing the sales of various books:

[image]

In the pivot table on the right, I would like to insert the author as a helper field to the right of the Book. For example, something like:

[image]

Is this possible to do in an Excel pivot table? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Open pivot table options dialog and go to Display tab, then check 'Classic PivotTable layout' checkbox.

[image]

After that in pivot table rows add 'Author' field and  remove subtotals for 'Book' field.

[image]

Comment: i'm using the 2013 version, but the latest versions must have this option as well.